# cannot resolve constructor GoogleSignInOptions

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I'm trying to follow the Google Sign-In tutorial from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#before_you_begin, but I'm receiving the following error when instantiating "GoogleSignInOPtions" class:

[image]

Can someone more experienced about Android Studio, Android Development, etc., point me where is the problem?

I have already tried to Clean and Rebuild the project, but no good..

Thank you so much!

Kind Regards,
Ivan Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(...)`. Currently you have `new GoogleSignInOptions(...)`.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
     GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```